# Editing an XML selector with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Ok my powershell and scripting skills are very simple so bear with me. I have an .xml document on multiple servers that has a couple of nodes that need changed without changing the entire XML. Im trying to create a simple command/batch or script that will change these modes rather than opening and manually edit them. Here is what needs changed as follows

```
<selector>
<ip address=“x.x.x.x” allow-undefined=“no” />
</selector>
```

I need to change it to

```
<selector>
<interface id=“listener” />
</selector>
```

Then a node

```
<selector>
<user-group name=“servername\SSH Access” />
</selector>
```

To

```
<selector>
<user-group name=“servername\SSH Access” allow-undefined=“no” />
</selector>
```

Finally same as above

```
<selector>
<user-group name=“servername\SSH Access” />
</selector>
```

To

```
<selector>
<user-group name=“servername\SSH Access” allow-undefined=“no” />
</selector>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What code have you tried? Did you know you can read the XML object by doing `[xml]$Document = Get-Content File.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml=[xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <selector>
     <ip ipaddress="123" allowundefined="no" />
   </selector>
"@

$xml.selector.RemoveChild($xml.selector.LastChild)
$ele=$xml.CreateElement("interface")
$attri=$xml.CreateAttribute("id")
$attri.Value="listener"
$ele.Attributes.Append($attri)
$xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($ele)
```

For you reference.

You can try above and modify it what you want.
You would get a lot of ideas from trial and error

Comment: Here is my stupidity how does it know which xml file to open? [filename.xml] ?!?